# Is creating new Wordpress post with custom post type and custom fields possible via XML-RPC?

Tags: python, wordpress, xml-rpc, custom-post-type

I've been trying to create new blog posts on my site using python and wordpress' XML-RPC API. So I came across [a wrapper](https://github.com/maxcutler/python-wordpress-xmlrpc) and tried it, but it seems it doesn't support creating posts with custom post type and fields. So I started looking for custom codes and came across this [bug report](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16476). Now I am confused. Is it even possible to do this? If yes, how? As I can find to code examples, it is proving a bit tough for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WordPress XML-RPC API does not currently support custom post types. However, support will be added in the forthcoming WordPress 3.4 release. You can find documentation for that on the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Posts).

I have a [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/xml-rpc-modernization/) that acts as a shim for WordPress 3.3 and earlier and adds functionality equivalent to that added in 3.4.

I have recently updated my python wrapper that you had found, and it now supports WordPress 3.4's new functionality. I have put up several examples in the library's documentation.

Essentially, you need to use the `post_type` field available as a parameter on the new `wp.*Post` XML-RPC methods.