# Writing WordPress Post Metadata with Python and Tribe Events Calendar

Tags: python, wordpress, metadata, xml-rpc

I need to use Python to write many posts to WordPress using a custom post type, specifically the tribe_event post type from Tribe Events Calendar (https://theeventscalendar.com/product/wordpress-events-calendar/). It has meta-data for the event start date and time, among other fields, which I need to access and assign but cannot find where to do so.

A similar article ([Is creating new Wordpress post with custom post type and custom fields possible via XML-RPC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052969/is-creating-new-wordpress-post-with-custom-post-type-and-custom-fields-possible)) seems to conclude this is not possible, but it's from 2012, and I can find no further information online.

I'm going about it like this:

```
from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client, WordPressPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.posts import GetPosts, NewPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods import posts

wp = Client('http://_MYURL/xmlrpc.php', 'myusername', 'mypassword')
```

Then, in order to look for the answer to my question, I can query several existing event posts like this:

```
events = wp.call(posts.GetPosts({'post_type': 'tribe_events', 'number': 100}))
```

And I can inspect one of the post objects like:

```
event = events[0]
dir(events)
```

but all I see is:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_def', 'comment_status', 'content', 'custom_fields', 'date', 'date_modified', 'definition', 'excerpt', 'guid', 'id', 'link', 'menu_order', 'mime_type', 'parent_id', 'password', 'ping_status', 'post_format', 'post_status', 'post_type', 'slug', 'sticky', 'struct', 'terms', 'thumbnail', 'title', 'user']
```

These are just the built-in post type values and none correspond to the start/end date data I'm looking to assign. If I look at:

```
event.custom_fields
```

I get

```
[]
```

and

```
event.date
```

contains the date the post was written, not the date of the event I'm trying to post. The data is also not in terms_names or terms.

**How do I find the namespaces needed to read and write values in custom WordPress post types, in Python?**

Note that the codex for the plugin states this data is not stored in the WordPress database, but is in a custom post type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All efforts indicate this is still not possible. None of the documentation that would apply to this question (http://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/wordpress.html?highlight=metadata) succeeds in discovering the namespaces of custom WordPress post types in Python. The author of the library wordpress_xmlrpc did not respond to a direct inquiry.